# Help me identify this small plant and how to take care of it

Tags: identification, houseplants, indoors

Please help me identify this plant. It was a gift and I don't know what plant it is.

I want to know what plant it is so that I can take care of it properly. It's starting to brown and some leaves are starting to fall, I think the way I water it is wrong.

Size: The plant + the pot, has a size comparable to a small mug or creamer pot.

Color: initially all green, but it's turning brown from the node and the stem :'(

Smell: it has a subtle smell i can't describe.

Leaves: i think you can say that it's scaly??? I'm not sure how to describe it.

I searched in google, and some plants with scaly leaves and with similar appearance are conifers. Is this a juniper? Hmm..I don't know. Im kinda lost, really. Please help me out. Disclaimer: I haven't seen a juniper in my life.

TIA

[image: **plant in a egg pot**]

[image: leaves]

Comment: For me it is Lycopodium or similar (so something between fern, "real" plants, and mooses). Are leaves soft on touch? (if not: it could be a juniper). Is the steam woody?

Comment: hey @GiacomoCatenazzi, thanks for helping out to identify the plant. To answer your question, yes the leaves are soft to touch and the stem looks woody (judging by the colour, it's not green stem). I've taken a look on the lycopodium and the succulent called Crassula muscosa (Sterling Herron's answer) and it think the latter looks more similar :) What do you think?

Comment: I think Crassula is more probable. And so I would think you are over-watering it.

Comment: yeah, I think you're right. I may have over watered it. I sprinkle water to it every morning T-T

Comment: It is a succulent, so it should like dry periods. If you see the tips turning yellowish, and the leaves shrinking (concave, with wrinkles) then you can water it. It is not a moss or an orchids (for water spraying).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a watchchain plant, a succulent called Crassula muscosa; here is a Dave’s garden page on it: https://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/2410/#b

It does look a bit wilty. It’s normal for the lower stem to get brown with age, but it may benefit from getting more direct sunlight, or water, hard to tell. The pot should be fine as they don’t require a lot of drainage like most succulents (and thus make a good houseplant).

A cool thing about them is that, if they are healthy, you can literally just pick off a branch and place it on the surface of the soil, and it will grow roots and start a new plant. You may try taking off some of the greener tips and placing them on soil or water to root on their own.

Comment: hi sterling herron, many thanks! that's very informative. Im hoping now that i can stop the wilting. I'll try to give it more sun and less water (since its a succulent) Thanks again.